# Count the number of minutes with datediff and substring

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, count, datediff

I have data like this

```
availabilities
[{"starts_at":"09:00","ends_at":"17:00"}]
```

I have query below and it works

```
select COALESCE(availabilities,'Total')      as availabilities,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(minute,start_at,end_at)) as 'Total Available Hours in Minutes'
from (
    select cast(availabilities as NVARCHAR)             as availabilities,
           cast(SUBSTRING(availabilities,16,5) as time) as start_at,
           cast(SUBSTRING(availabilities,34,5) as time) as end_at
    from alfy.dbo.daily_availabilities
)x
GROUP by ROLLUP(availabilities);
```

Result

```
availabilities                                          Total Available Hours in Minutes
[{"starts_at":"09:00","ends_at":"17:00"}]                                            480
```

How if the data like below

```
availabilities
[{"starts_at":"10:00","ends_at":"13:30"},{"starts_at":"14:00","ends_at":"18:00"}]
[{"starts_at":"09:00","ends_at":"12:30"},{"starts_at":"13:00","ends_at":"15:30"},{"starts_at":"16:00","ends_at":"18:00"}]
```

How to count the number of minutes over two or more time ranges?

Comment: Instead of doing your own parsing (or rather chopping and cutting), I recommend you look into this: [Working with JSON data in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server), it even includes a 38 minute tutorial video.

Comment: @PeterB Hi Peter, i'm not using json

Comment: Your input text conforms with JSON standards, which makes it suitable for processing as JSON as in the link that I posted. What reason do you have to deny that it is JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have JSON data use [OPENJSON (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) to parse it, e.g.:

```sql
create table dbo.daily_availabilities (
  id int,
  availabilities nvarchar(max) --JSON
);

insert dbo.daily_availabilities (id, availabilities) values
  (1, N'[{"starts_at":"09:00","ends_at":"17:00"}]'),
  (2, N'[{"starts_at":"10:00","ends_at":"13:30"},{"starts_at":"14:00","ends_at":"18:00"}]'),
  (3, N'[{"starts_at":"09:00","ends_at":"12:30"},{"starts_at":"13:00","ends_at":"15:30"},{"starts_at":"16:00","ends_at":"18:00"}]');

select id, sum(datediff(mi, starts_at, ends_at)) as total_minutes
from dbo.daily_availabilities
cross apply openjson(availabilities) with (
  starts_at time,
  ends_at time
) av
group by id
```

| id | total_minutes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 480 |
| 2 | 450 |
| 3 | 480 |

Comment: Hi, I'm not using json and the data already exists, can't change or enter any other data

Comment: Ok, but it looks like JSON.

Comment: yes I use metabase, the query is like sql server and mysql